# Questions about Molecular dynamics code in "Understanding Molecular Simulation: From Algorithms to Applications"

Tags: fortran

**You will need to have read the book to answer my questions.**

-Background-
I'm trying to learn Molecular Dynamics and I've started with books that are supposed to be introductory but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the equations or their explanations. I have tried probably 6 or 7 different books, starting with the introduction chapters and then looking through the book for code I could replicate to give me some context for the equations as I cannot understand them. It's pretty obvious that they expect you to have a lot of prerequisite physics knowledge (and it seems like specifically MD knowledge) to understand how the equations translate to a piece of code. I've taken a physics course and a 3D physics engine course but this knowledge has not been helpful in this endeavor.  The only code I've been able to find is in **"Understanding Molecular Simulation: From Algorithms to Applications"** and I have some questions about it that I cannot find the answers to in the book. **If you any prerequisite books or courses that are more beginner friendly to help give me context for the material in this book, that would be amazing** -Background End-

This is exactly how the code shows up in the book and I read you're supposed to place subroutines after the main program ends so thats what I did. Because I can only find fortran tutorials that work with very small pieces of code, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to have `stop`, `end`, and `return` at all the places it shows up here, if `implicit none` is where its supposed to be and if I'm supposed to have each subroutine in a different file or anything like. 
The loops are basically the same as in python so I've been able to understand some of the code already but I don't see the larger picture yet.

The main problem I am facing is that a bunch of the variables I used are not declared anywhere in the book (although I found explanations as to what they represent for some of them) which may be why the program won't run. I get this error message "Launch failed. Binary not found".

How do you declare the variables `delt`, `tmax`, `f`(force), `en`(energy), `ranf`, `lattice_pos`, `x`, `v`, `temp`, `xm`, `dt`, `xr`, `box`, `r2i`, `r6i`, `ff`, `xx`, and `vi`? Some of these might not even be variables but I don't think they are built into fortran because I can't find any info on them. Also I'm guessing tmax would be the same number as npart (N particles) so why would they use 2 different variables?

What do these variables mean? (except `f` and `en` as I could find them)

Where are the x,y,z coordinates of each atom being stored? I would assume that they would be stored in either 1 list (or whatever the equivalent is in fortran) storing lists with 3 values each (for x,y,z) or 3 lists contaiting all the x,y,z coordinates in each list, in the `init` subroutine. However that is not the case as only `x` and and `v` are looped through.

Why is `en` an input for `force()` when it is immediately set to 0 at the beginning of the subroutine? Couldn't you just declare it inside the function without it being an input?

```
program main
call init

t=0
do while (t.lt.tmax)
call force(f,en)
call integrate(f,en)
t=t+delt
call sample
enddo
stop
end

subroutine init
sumv=0
sumv2=0
do i=1, npart
    x(i)=lattice_pos(i)
    v(i)=(ranf()-0.5)
    sumv=sumv+v(1)
    sumv2=sumv2+v(i)**2
enddo
sumv=sumv/npart
sumv2=sumv2/npart
fs=sqrt(3*temp/sumv2)
do i=1,npart
    v(i)=(v(i)-sumv)*fs
    xm(i)=x(i)-v(i)*dt
enddo
return

subroutine force(f, en)
en=0
do i=1, npart-1
    do j=i+1, npart
        xr=xr-box*nint(xr/box)
        r2=xr**2
        if (r2.lt.rc2) then
            r2i=1/r2
            r6i=r2i**3
            ff=48*r2i*r6i*(r6i-0.5)
            f(i)=f(i)+ff*xr
            f(j)=f(j)-ff*xr
            en=en+4*r6i*(r6i-1)-ecut
        endif
    enddo
enddo
return
end

subroutine integrate(f,en)
sumv=0
sumv2=0
dp i=1,npart
    xx=2*x(i)-xm(i)+delt**2*f(i)
    vi=(xx-xm(i))/(2*delt)
    sumv=sumv+vi
    sumv2=sumv2+vi**2
    xm(i)=x(i)
    x(i)=xx
enddo
temp=sumv2/(3*npart)
etot=(en+0.5*sumv2)/npart
return
end
    implicit none
end program main
```

Comment: I upvoted the question for the first sentence - which saved me reading any more.  A very useful tip.

Comment: If we have to read a book to answer your question it is way too broad for Stack Overflow,

Comment: The classic in the area is "Computer Simulation of Liquids" by Allen and Tildesley. There is a new edition out, see http://global.oup.com/booksites/content/9780198803195/ . This is sat on my shelf but I haven't worked through it yet, but I would recommend it in the hope that the code is updated, as the original would be very old fashioned nowadays. Don't know your book but the above looks rather schematic (and old fashioned)  - I would suggest you buy a good Fortran book (e.g.https://global.oup.com/academic/product/modern-fortran-explained-9780198811893?lang=en&cc=se) or attend a course.

Comment: @greg-449 if you have to read a book doesnt that make the question more specific? Anyways where would be a better place to ask this question?

Comment: I think it's perverse to close this question as too broad.  There used to be a *too narrow* reason for closing which would have been more appropriate, but that was dropped.  As it stands, if OP were to make the question a little less specific (i.e. broaden it a bit) this would be a good question.  It already has a good answer, containing material interesting to anyone updating old scientific codes.

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help must include a [mcve] **and a complete description of what the expected behavior is and how the current outcome differs from expected outcome** *in the question itself*. If a question requires us to read a book in order to understand the question, as greg said, the question needs revising.

Comment: @TylerH ok well again, is there a more appropriate website to post this question on?

Comment: @TylerBloom The issue here is not so much the topicality, but the broadness of the question. This is asking, essentially, a whole series of questions. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask (for example, the line " If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much" is relevant here)

Answer (score 3):

The example code in "Understanding Molecular Simulation: From Algorithms to Applications", as in many other textbooks, is pseudocode. It is not complete (lack of declarations, for instance) and meant to illustrate the algorithms a bit more explicitly than "just the mathematics". In this book, it is confusing because they write incomplete Fortran for the pseudocode.

This is still a good "general problem": understand how old-fashioned textbook material with Fortran can be used :-)

At http://www.acmm.nl/molsim/frenkel_smit/index.html (website of the Amsterdam Center for Multiscale Modeling), you can find actual Fortran code for the book http://www.acmm.nl/molsim/frenkel_smit/README.html As Ian Bush writes, the code is old-fashioned and the Allen & Tildesley book has an update *and* updated code: https://github.com/Allen-Tildesley/

As for your questions:

1. How do you declare the variables delt, tmax, f(force), en(energy), ranf, lattice_pos, x, v, temp, xm, dt, xr, box, r2i, r6i, ff, xx, and vi? Some of these might not even be variables but I don't think they are built into fortran because I can't find any info on them. Also I'm guessing tmax would be the same number as npart (N particles) so why would they use 2 different variables?

   You have to read the chapters about the algorithms to make sense of the variables. A list of them is available on page "xxi" of the book however.
2. Where are the x,y,z coordinates of each atom being stored? I would assume that they would be stored in either 1 list (or whatever the equivalent is in fortran) storing lists with 3 values each (for x,y,z) or 3 lists contaiting all the x,y,z coordinates in each list, in the init subroutine. However that is not the case as only x and and v are looped through.

   Here again, the pseudocode is a bit limitative. You have several options declare the variables: (i) The authors (see link above for files) use "common blocks", a Fortran-specific type of global variables. (ii) Module variables, available in Fortran 90 and more recent, are "better global variables". (iii) Encapsulate all the data in derived types that you can declare in the main program and pass to subroutines.

   The positions are stored (in the examples) as array `x(npmax)`, `y(npmax)` and `z(npmax)`. `npmax` is the maximum number of particles. This is not shown in the pseudo-code. Note that in more recent versions of Fortran (90 and later), you can write vector operations such as `x = x + v*dt` (where x and v are the position and velocity of *all* particles and dt is the scalar timestep).
3. Why is en an input for force() when it is immediately set to 0 at the beginning of the subroutine? Couldn't you just declare it inside the function without it being an input?

   It is common, but not mandatory, in Fortran to pass variables that need an update as arguments to subroutine. Programming styles vary.